# TypeScript mapped types inference not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given this function:

```js
export const combineValidators = <Input extends { [P in keyof Input]: (val: string) => Err }, Err>(
  validators: Input
) => (values: { [P in keyof Input]?: unknown }): { [P in keyof Input]: Err } => {
  // Ignore implementation.
  return {} as { [P in keyof Input]: Err };
};
```

And this usage:

```js
const validator = combineValidators({
  name: (val) => val ? undefined : 'error',
  email: (val) => val ? undefined : 'error'
});

const errors = validator({
  name: 'Lewis',
  email: 'lewis@mercedes.com'
});
```

I would expect TypeScript to be able to infer the return type as:

```js
// Expected: `errors` to be inferred as:
interface Ret {
  name: string | undefined;
  email: string | undefined;
}
```

However it's inferred as:

```js
// Actual: `errors` inferred as:
interface Ret {
  name: {};
  email: {};
}
```

I've created a [live example in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20const%20combineValidators%20%3D%20%3CInput%20extends%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20Input%5D%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20Err%20%7D%2C%20Err%3E(%0D%0A%20%20validators%3A%20Input%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20(values%3A%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20Input%5D%3F%3A%20unknown%20%7D)%3A%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20Input%5D%3A%20Err%20%7D%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%7D%20as%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20Input%5D%3A%20Err%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20validator%20%3D%20combineValidators(%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'error'%2C%0D%0A%20%20email%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'error'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20errors%20%3D%20validator(%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20'Lewis'%2C%0D%0A%20%20email%3A%20'lewis%40mercedes.com'%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Expected%3A%20%60errors%60%20to%20be%20inferred%20as%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20interface%20Ret%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20name%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20email%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Actual%3A%20%60errors%60%20to%20be%20inferred%20as%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20interface%20Ret%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20name%3A%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20email%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D) demonstrating the issue.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Err` will not be inferred in the way you expect it. It might be simpler to use the `ReturnType` conditional type to extract the return types from `Input`:

```
type ReturnTypes<T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any[]) => any>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>
}

export const combineValidators = <Input extends Record<keyof Input, (val: unknown) => any>>(
  validators: Input
) => (values: Record<keyof Input, unknown>): ReturnTypes<Input> => {
  return {} as ReturnTypes<Input>;
};

const validator = combineValidators({
  name: (val) => val ? undefined : 'error',
  email: (val) => val ? undefined : 'error'
});

const errors = validator({
  name: 'Lewis',
  email: 'lewis@mercedes.com'
});
```

We can even go a bit further and if you specify parameters types in the validator function, you can get type checking for the fields of the object passed to `validator`:

```
type ParamTypes<T extends Record<keyof T, (a: any) => any>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: Parameters<T[P]>[0]
}

type ReturnTypes<T extends Record<keyof T, (...a: any[]) => any>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]>
}

export const combineValidators = <Input extends Record<keyof Input, (val: unknown) => any>>(
  validators: Input
) => (values: ParamTypes<Input>): ReturnTypes<Input> => {
  return {} as ReturnTypes<Input>;
};

const validator = combineValidators({
  name: (val: string) => val ? undefined : 'error',
  email: (val) => val ? undefined : 'error', // if we leave it out, we still get unknown
  age: (val: number) => val ? undefined : 'error'
});

const errors = validator({
  name: 'Lewis',
  email: 'lewis@mercedes.com',
  age: 0
});

const errors2 = validator({
  name: 'Lewis',
  email: 'lewis@mercedes.com',
  age: "0" // type error
});
```

Comment: Amazing! I need to get better at TypeScript. Only issue is `ReturnType` seems to ignore `undefined`; I'd have expected `ReturnType<() => string | undefined>` to result in `string | undefined`?

Comment: @riscarrott are you sure you have strict null checks on ?

Comment: Surprisingly no I don't, works perfectly with strict null checks on, thanks you!